# Java: When declaring objects or ints

Tags: java, object, declare

When creating an object(or anything) in java, what is the difference between doing, for example,

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

instead of doing

```
Dog d;
```

and then later, finishing it off(sometimes inside and at the beginning of a method) with

```
d = new Dog();
```

Wouldn't the first one be more simple and easier? Why do people do it the second way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the following scenario. Assume the constructor of `Dog` can throw an exception:

```
try {
    Dog d = new Dog();    
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // treat exception
}

d.bark();
```

This won't compile because `d` is not visible outside the `try` block. What you need to do is this:

```
Dog d = null;
try {
    d = new Dog();    
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // treat exception
}
if(d != null) d.bark();
```

And there are many other situations like this. For example, you might have an if-else block where `d` is initialized differently based on some condition:

```
Dog d = null;
if(/* condition */)
    d = new Dog("Lassie");   
} else {
    d = new Dog("Sam");
}
d.bark();
```

Comment: There is big difference between `Dog d = null;` and `Dog d;`. I believe the OP asks about the latter form.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: It's never a good idea to declare objects without initializing them anyway.

Comment: @Tudor, sometimes it is a very good idea to declare an object without initializing it. Objects declared `final` can only be set once, and sometimes it's not known what it needs to be set to at the point it is declared.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, what is the difference? I thought `Dog d;` == `null`.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: no, as far as compiler is concerned, `Dog d` declares *uninitialized* variable which you cannot use (it won't compile). `Dog d = null` defines a variable with `null` value, which you can use, i.e. to check for null (or trigger NPE when accessed). See my answer.

Comment: `Dog d;` compiles just fine, and defaults to null.  (Some compilers will complain if you don't initialize it at _some_ point, but none I'm familiar with will complain if you e.g. initialize it on the next line.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: an uninitialized **field** defaults to null. An uninitialized local variable has no default value. It **must** be explicitely initialized before it's used. And that is not compiler-dependant.

Comment: My bad: it must be explicitly initialized, but the point was -- not necessarily on the same line that it was declared.

Answer (score 3):

The question lacks some important context.  There is a substantial difference if the variable definition and the usage are in separate scopes.  For example:

```
class A { 
  Dog d;

  void foo() { d = new Dog(); }
}
```

...allows Dog to be accessed by every member of `class A`.

If the usage is in the same scope,

```
class A {
  void foo() {
     Dog d;
     d = new Dog();
  }
}
```

...then it's an issue of readability, as the code will run the same with it in one or two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't always know how to construct the object when you declare it.
For example:

```
Dog dog;
if ("M".equals(sex)) {
    dog = new Dog("Medor");
}
else {
    dog = new Dog("Mirza");
}
dog.walk();
```

Comment: This is one of the place which begs for `final Dog dog = Dog.create("M")` or at least extra local method.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - it only *begs for* that if you have a mindset that says that deferred initialization is intrinsically bad.  I (for one) am perfectly happy with writing and reading code that uses this feature appropriately.

Comment: @StephenC: +1, I wasn't really aware that with deferred initialization you can still use `final` (`final Dog dog;`)!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of reasons. One reason might be that the initialization depends on runtime-determined conditions. For instance,

```
Animal pet;
...
if(input == 0) pet = new Dog();
else pet = new Cat();
...
pet.sleep();
```

Comment: You example will not compile as `pet` is not guaranteed to be assigned.

Comment: @Steve Kuo Edited. Does that compile?

Answer (score 1):

This is only **declaration** a reference (you say `d` will have type `Dog`):

```
Dog d;
```

This is creating a new object, and **assigning** it to reference variable `d`:

```
new Dog();
```

You can combine it because you often do both, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a good idea to *habitually* separate the declaration and initialization

- there are some circumstances where you *need* to do this (see the try catch example),
- there are some circumstances where it improves code readability (see the Max Schmidt's example),
- there are some circumstances where it makes your code more robust.

To illustrate the last point, consider Max Schmidt's example modified:

```
Dog d = null;
if (input.equals("lab")) {
   d = new Labrador();
} else if (input.equals("bull")) {
   d = new Bulldog();
}
d.walk();
```

See the bug?  If `input` is neither `"lab"` or `"bull"`, the code will die when we walk a `null` dog.

However, if we remove the initialization of `d`, then the compiler will tell us that there is a path through the code which leaves `d` uninitialized.  If we are paying attention, we see the bug and fix it before the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

It's a crude example of lazy initialization.  In your program, it is possible that you may never need an actual instance of the Dog object.  In those cases, you could simply declare the Dog reference, which does not consume much memory and later initialize it when required.

Comment: Also what @Tudor said, very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Object Creation and Object Declaration. You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

When you do `Dog d = new Dog();`, you are declaring a variable `d` of type `Dog` and by using the `new` operator you are creating the variable.

So you would normally declare the variable that you need at the beginning and create them only when they are really used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason, it is just a **poor coding practice**. Since you cannot use `d` before it is initialized, there is no point in declaring it earlier:

```
Dog d;
//...you cannot use `d` in any way! It won't compile
d = new Dog();
//now you can
```

This however:

```
Dog d = null;
//...
d = new Dog();
```

makes sense as someone might check for `null` (lazy-initialization, etc.)

For the sake of simplicity you should actually prefer:

```
final Dog d = new Dog();
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one may be more useful in the cases where you have something like try/catch where Dog will be created, creating dog instance shouldn't stop your other logic in that method. If dog instance is there you want to use after try/catch, otherwise continue your logic.

If you use first syntax inside try/catch, you can't use it outside.

```
try {
    Dog d = new Dog();    
} catch(Exception ex) {

}

d.methodCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is no other way than the second one, for example if dog is a superclass of Labrador and Bulldog:

```
Dog d;

if (input == "lab"){
  d = new Labrador();
}else if {
 d = new  Bulldog();
}

d.urinate():
```